# Access a list item stored in key value pair inside a list of map

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am using **flutter/dart** and I have run into following problem.

I have a list of map like this.

```
var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
        'answer': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White']
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answer': ['Deer', 'Tiger', 'Lion', 'Bear']
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite movie?',
        'answer': ['Die Hard', 'Due Date', 'Deep Rising', 'Dead or Alive']
      },
    ];
```

Now suppose I need to get the string `Tiger` from this list. How do I do that? Dart is seeing this as `List<Map<String, Object>> questions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a more portable way with a function:

```dart
String getAnswer(int question, int answer) {
   return (questions[question]['answer'] as List<String>)[answer];
}

// Get 'Tiger'
String a = getAnswer(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert object in list in following way and then use index to get any value.

```
var p = questions[1]['answer'] as List<String>;
print(p[1]);
```